# MySql Reporting System with Basic Interface

Tags: php, mysql, reporting

We need a MySQL reporting / monitoring system. Our end-users want to see some informations from databases. They need *read-only* access permission. We don't want to use PhpMyAdmin because PHPMYADMIN's interface is a little complicated for our end-users.  (They don't know SQL or other programming languages)

Because of this we need more basic interface. User's can select columns which what to see, and order them according to they want.

For example there will be a table, users can columns and order datas. Datas will come from our database.

Comment: If they are end-users, what exactly do you need them to monitor? Can you describe your requirements more closely? This might be easiest to solve through a simple custom PHP script though

Comment: Actually, our managers want to check database, for example they want to list our customers etc. etc. . But they can't use PHPMYADMIN . Because of this we need more more more basically interface :) We don't want to lost time for writing a script for this :) In shortly, we need an script which list datas like a table from database and filtering it easily. If there is any script related with this, we can improve it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following reporting tools :

- [Smart Report Maker](http://mysqlreports.com):  very easy to install and use can do precisely the features you mentioned (i.e., select specific columns, tables, filters, ..etc.) in addition to many advanced features.
- [Report Engine](https://mysqlreports.com/mysql-reporting-tools/smart-report-engine/): A new [PHP reporting framework](https://mysqlreports.com/mysql-reporting-tools/smart-report-engine/), that will help you add the reporting capabilities you need to your project.
- [Reportico](http://www.reportico.org/site/index.php): a web reporting tool with a very easy to use wizard-style interface

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a PHP script *somewhere* that does what you need, but in my experience, trying them all out,  customizing them and fixing crappy code can easily cost more time than writing it yourself. But maybe you get lucky, and somebody knows something. Other than that, I guess you'll just have to browse the net.

One unorthodox idea that comes to mind is Microsoft Access. It's relatively easy to build a reporting application in it (including filters and such); connecting to a MySQL database is easy through the [ODBC connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.1.html).

It wouldn't be completely out of the box, though, and of course it wouldn't run in the browser, so it may not be the right thing.

Answer (score -1):

Since you tagged php, here is a tutorial:

http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql/

As for finding an existing script, it will probably be quicker and easier to write your own.